# Масштабирование канала связи

Tags: apache, масштабирование, windows-server

Привет всем. Нужно как-то распределить юзеров между несколькими серверами с таким условием: запрос менять нельзя. То есть, совсем грубо представляется так: юзер набирает в адресной строке "http://www.site.ru", а фактически попадает на www[0-9].site.ru, притом 1) в адресной строке видит www.site.ru, 2) важен канал, ибо причина собсно расширения в том, что его не хватает(прокси не катит).

Пока интересуют любые решения и общие тычки "куда копать"

ЗЫ: знаю, вопрос больше к Руткоду, но может именно .htaccess + скрипт будет работать, что-то такое слышал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS Round Robin вам в руки и никаких .htaccess и скриптов не надо.

Comment: Ага, вариант хороший) Вопрос только - на обычном VPS это реализуемо? Или с хостером общаться придется?

Comment: Тут, наверное, к хостинг провайдеру или регистратору, ибо для реализации с VPS, всё равно придётся обращаться к регистратору + нужно 2 DNS сервера с разными IP адресами поднимать.

Comment: Неплохо, блин. А вот на <a href="http://www.dyndns.com/services/?via=topnav">что-то подобное</a> есть смысл заглядываться?

Comment: Лишняя трата денег, я думаю )))
Я dyndns сам пользуюсь, но именно в этой ситуации он, наверное, ничего полезного не даст.
Надо настроить зону у регистратора, т.е. добавить туда кучу записей с одним названием и разными IP адресами и... PROFIT. (http://info.nic.ru/st/8/out_263.shtml)

Comment: Хммм а <a href="http://dyn.com/enterprise-dns/dynect-platform/dynect-round-robin-load-balancing">так</a> + <a href="http://www.dyndns.com/services/dynectsmb/">так<a>? =) Тут просто еще проблема в том, что эту штуку хочется (полу-)автоматизировать и ~$2/месяц не смертельно совсем)

Comment: Звучит многообещающе, буду признателен если напишете о результатах тестирования подобного сервиса.